# ngOnit not getting triggerd

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular5

I have two components : TileComponent.ts and FullScreenComponent.ts.

On clicking the TileComponent, the FullScreenComponent opens up. In the TileComponent,I have the following code. ngOnInit() method gets triggered whenever the TileComponent loads.

**TileComponent.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("TileCompnent :ngOnInit");        

    this.crossDomainService.globalSelectors.subscribe(selectors => {
      globalCountries = selectors.jurisdiction || [];
      this.getArticles(globalCountries);
    });

    // Multiple Language
    this.crossDomainService.globalLanguage.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("TileCompnent :ngOnInit : crossDomainService");
      this.getArticles(globalCountries || countries);
    });
  }
```

Now on closing the FullScreenComponent leads to the loading of the TileComponent but this time I see that ngOnInit() method is not getting triggered.

Can anyone help me to know any reason this is not working?

[image]

tile.component.html:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
      <a
        (click)="openFullScreen(article)"
        *ngFor="let article of articles"
        [ngClass]="getItemClassNames(article)"
        class="item"
      >
</div>
```

tile.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("TileCompnent :ngOnInit");
    const countries =
      this.crossDomainService.initialGlobalSelectors &&
      this.crossDomainService.initialGlobalSelectors.jurisdiction.length
        ? this.crossDomainService.initialGlobalSelectors.jurisdiction
        : [];
    this.getArticles(countries);

    let globalCountries;

    this.crossDomainService.globalSelectors.subscribe(selectors => {
      globalCountries = selectors.jurisdiction || [];
      this.getArticles(globalCountries);
    });

    // Multiple Language
    this.crossDomainService.globalLanguage.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("TileCompnent :ngOnInit : crossDomainService");
      this.getArticles(globalCountries || countries);
    });
  }
    openFullScreen(article: ArticlePreview) {
        this.crossDomainService.openFullScreen(article);
      }
```

full-screen.component.html:

```
<div class="layout-center-wrapper" [hidden]="isPolicyShown">
  <app-header></app-header>

  <div class="row wrapper">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

<app-policy [hidden]="!isPolicyShown"></app-policy>
```

header.component.html:

```
<header class="row header">
  <p class="header__title">
    Application Name
    <a (click)="closeFullScreen()" class="header__close">
      <span class="icon icon_close"></span>
    </a>
  </p>
</header>
```

header.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CrossDomainService } from '../../core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.less']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private crossDomainService: CrossDomainService, private analyticsService: AnalyticsService) {}

  closeFullScreen() {
    this.crossDomainService.closeFullScreen();    
  }
}
```

Comment: Easiest way to fix this is to use ngif on your modal.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnInit` lifecycle is only run when the view of the component is first rendered.

Since the old `Tile Component` is not destroyed and is always in the background even when the `FullScreenComponent` is displayed, the lifecycle hook never gets triggered even when you close the component.
( I am assuming you are not using the router to navigate, but use it as a popup since there is a close button as shown in the question )

Cannot help you isolate the issue or help you with suggestions unless you share some code. But the reason for ngOnInit not firing as per the question is because the component is not re-created.

Update :
I still can't realise why you need to trigger the ngOnInit ? If you just want to execute the code inside, make it a separate function say `initSomething` then call it inside ngOnInit to execute it the first time. Now if you just invoke this function on `crossDomainService.closeFullScreen` you get the desired effect.

To trigger the function whenever the closeFullScreen is called, you can create a `Subject` in the `crossDomainService` Service, and subscribe this subject it inside the `ngOnInit()`, and run the `initSomething` function mentioned above everytime it emits a value. Inside the `closeFullScreen` function, all you have to now do is do a `Subject.next()`

Pardon the brevity since I am away from my desk and typing on mobile, though the explanation should be enough to develop the code on your own.

Comment: Thanks Dhananjai for your response. I have updated the code details. Can you please help me here to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple workaround would be to use changedetectorRef to hook up the initial state of component.

```
`import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`
```

and insert it in constructor and you can keep OnInit function blank

`constructor(){
 this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();}`